# Sending e-mail without refresh the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a page with a contact-us form located at the bottom.

What I am trying to achieve - send an email from the site without post back that'll reload all the page and move the customer to the top of the page(the contact-us form is at the bottom).

Instead of that - The customer will press the send button, and then some gesture that the mail was sent will appear.

I know how to send mail with the regular approach, what I am trying to accomplish is to send it from the client side with jquery.ajax - is it the best way for that scenario?

What I did was that, **Client side**:

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {       
var fullName = $('#txt_fullName').val();
var fromEmail = $('#txt_email').val();
var comments = $('#txtArea_message').val();
var fromPhone = $('#txt_phone').val();
var data = "{'name': '" + name + "', 'fromEmail': '" +
       fromEmail + "', 'comments': '" + comments + "', 'fromPhone': '" + fromPhone + "'}";

if (contactus == 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/sentMail",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    })
}else if (contactus == 1)
    return false;
 })
```

In the **server side** i have this:

```
tring sender_email = txt_email.Text;
string sender_fullName = txt_fullName.Text;
string sender_phone = txt_phone.Text;
string sender_message = txtArea_message.Text;

MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("XXX@gmail.com", "Site");
MyMailMessage.To.Add("XXX@gmail.com");
MyMailMessage.Subject = "messge from site";
MyMailMessage.Body = "message";
MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
try
{
    SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
    SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);          
}

catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

It doesn't work - and I don't know why(how can I debug that using Google chrome?)

Comment: where is data variables ?

Comment: If you're already familiar with regular approach (and especially if you already have working code for that) the fastest way to achieve this would be to include SEND button and related controls into an UpdatePanel. This way you keep all your familiar code and without any changes to the code avoid full page postback

Comment: Are you running this on a server that actually has working mail sending software installed ?

Comment: start by explaining `doesn't work`...far too many variables. What happens, what does work and what doesn't work. Also in JS where is `contactus` defined

Comment: 1) I don't want to use the update panel as it an old tech.. 2)With the regular approach it works. 3)contactus is not an issue cause i tried it without that parameter and it doesn't work also, I don't know if anything work because i don't know how to debug it:)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uptownapps/QBvZu/

In this example, my form has `id="contactForm"` which is how I will access it with jQuery.

```
    // We are looking to intercept the "submit" event on the form
    // whether that comes from a user clicking the "submit" button
    // or hitting "enter" on their keyboard while on a form element.
    $( document ).on('submit', '#contactForm', function( event ) {

        // We are going to handle the interaction with the server ourselves
        // so we want to prevent the browser from performing the default action
        event.preventDefault();

        // serialize() on a from element will create the query string data
        // like you would typically see in a GET request
        // (i.e. "name=UptownApps&email=support@getuptownapps.com" etc.)
        var formData = $('#contactForm').serialize();

        $.ajax({

            // Send the request to the same place the form was originally going to
            url: $('#contactForm').attr('action'),

            // In this case I'm using POST. 'GET' is also acceptable.
            type: 'POST',

            // This callback function fires after successfully communicating
            // with the server
            success: function(data) { // data contains server's response

                $('#contactForm').slideUp(400); // Hide the form
                $('#successMessage').slideDown(400); // Show the success message

            },

            // Error callback fires if there was an issue communicating with the server
            // Or a non-200 HTTP status is returned
            error: function(data) { // data contains server's response

                $('#errorMessage').slideDown(400); // Show the error message

            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Sorry (hit the enter key - didn't manage to edit it),Can You please elaborate more on the process as I don't understand.. serialize() - post back all input elements and there values on the query string back to the server? How can I debug this using Google chrome? can you direct my to a good walk-through manual that describe how to do that using Google chrome developer panel? and please, can you explain what is not good in my original post. as it didn't work. please response in your original post. Thanks

Comment: I have added comments to my code. In your code, you are not preventing the defaults from happening (the browser submitting the form natively). You are also creating JSON data by hand, which is not needed. You are also not defining a success or failure function in your .ajax call. I don't know what the rest of your server-side code looks like so I can't help you there. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I have added an alert('success') in the success function of ajax -it worked. but no mail has arrived.The url: $('#contactForm').attr('action')->action="Default.aspx/sendMail" and I tried to send the parameters not as you suggested(i didnt know the order of them, in debug it shows all the view state)-is it necessary? i sent it like that -  var data= "{'name': '" + fullName + "', 'fromEmail': '" +
       fromEmail + "', 'comments': '" + comments + "', 'fromPhone': '" + fromPhone + "'}"; ans I have these parametrs values also - I chekcked them and they are fine. How can i debug the server side?

Comment: I have already advised against crafting your JSON string manually when serialize will allow the browser to do the work in the exact same manner as if it were submitting the form natively. As far as debugging your server-side code, you will need to use the debugging tools build into your IDE (most likely Visual Studio if you are writing C#). I don't know what the rest of your server-side environment (ASP.NET, MVC, or what?) looks like but you might want to check out @serene's answer of using an object with the same property names and let the ASP model binder create the object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using jquery to scroll to the top of the page after the ajax call is done.

```
$.ajax({url: '/'}).done(function(data) {window.scrollTo(0,0);});
```

Answer (score 0):

The general answer would be that you would achieve that using AJAX and you could therefore research Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX. However, since you generally seem to have figured that out, but have steered on the wrong path, here are a few notes.

You are posting to the page `Default.aspx/sentMail` which I'm not really sure how IIS handles it, but as far as I can tell, it would open up Default.aspx and ignore the sentMail part (it would not send it with a POST parameter `sentMail` as it looks like you're expecting. If you would like to use this approach, you would need to post to Default.aspx (or whatever page), but you would need to set the param `data` for the `$.ajax` as noted [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (search the page for POST). Then, instead of the server-side code you posted, you would need to get the variables from POST, not the controls. However, this is not a very efficient way of doing this type of thing so I won't go into details about that.

A better way would be to make a web service with a method `SendEmail` and use that using 
[Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515101%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This would be much easier, faster and cleaner.

I would also like to add two notes.

1. You wrote on the client side you use `$('#btnSubmit')`. If you're using predictive naming for the control (button) that's okay, but that's not the default behaviour so in case you were not aware, you should use `$('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>')` for the client id of the control.
2. If you open up a web service to send emails, anyone can just call it whenever they want, how many times they want which leaves you open to all kinds of attacks. I suggest you implement some kind of check, perhaps render a variable (a GUID perhaps) on the page that you store in the session and make the web service method check if the sent parameter is actually in the session before sending the mail. Note that you'll need to add an `EnableSession=true` attribute as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be able to access the session from the web method.

Comment: Can you please explain why I have to use $('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>')? if i put a 'debugger' in the '$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () { debugger' - the debugger is stopping there.. and yes it strange because it's an asp:button - doesn't it suppose to have a different id when it's rendering?

Comment: ASP.NET works in such a way that it generates control IDs so they will be unique. This means that when you name your control btnSubmit, it will not have the name btnSubmit and that is why you get a different id there. A lot more detailed explanation can be found on [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss(v=vs.100).ASPX).

Comment: I am familiar with that, But as I wrote "if i put a 'debugger' in the '$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () { debugger' - the debugger is stopping there." , Which means that the id is OK. if I 'inspect the element (submit button) I see the id as "btnSubmit". No?

Comment: Sorry, misread you're comment. If it's working then you probably have the ClientIDMode property of the control set to Static so it's always exactly what you type. Look at the _ClientID property_ part of the page I mentioned in my comment. Just make sure you don't have two of the same ID's on one page and you're code will be fine if you use static.

Comment: That's what I dont understand, the button is configured like that:    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="send" CssClass="rounded" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />, so how come his ID remains untouched?

Comment: Maybe you've set the default ClientMode in the web.config or in the page directive? Search the above mentioned link for `You can set the default ClientIDMode` for info on how this works. If it's not that, I really have no clue how that can work - maybe you have another control that does have the `btnSubmit` ID, but it's not that button, it's something else?

Comment: Nope didn't set the clientIDMode anywhere.. Strange:)

Comment: Then you should definitely check if there's another control with that ID on your page. Try opening the page up and use developer tools/firebug (I know this works in Chrome and Firebug, not sure of IE), open the console, write $('#btnSubmit') and press enter, then hover your mouse over the result and it should highlight the control on your page. Check if it's actually the control you're expecting. If it is, I have no idea how that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your client javascript seems fine but it would be better if you map the properties to an object like this on C#:

```
public class Mail
{
public string FullName {get; set;}
public string FromEmail {get; set;}
public string ToEmail{get; set;}
public string Comments {get; set;}
public string FromPhone {get; set;}
}
```

And change your jquery to this (map properties of Class Mail to your View Input Content):

```
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {       
        var fullName = $('#txt_fullName').val();
        var fromEmail = $('#txt_email').val();
        var comments = $('#txtArea_message').val();
        var fromPhone = $('#txt_phone').val();
        var data = {
                    FullName: fullname,
                    FromEmail: fromEmail,
                    Comments: comments,
                    FromPhone: fromPhone,
                    };

        if (contactus == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/sentMail",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            })
        }else if (contactus == 1)
            return false;
    });
```

And your Function on server side must be an webmethod  and be as below:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SentMail(Mail mail)
{
    //use properties of Class Mail to send
    MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
    MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("XXX@gmail.com", "Site");
    MyMailMessage.To.Add(mail.To);
    MyMailMessage.Subject = mail.Comments;
    MyMailMessage.Body = mail.Comments;
    MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    try
    {
        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);          
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return "";
}
```